# Esc k sometimes types M-k in Emacs wih evil-mode

Tags: emacs

Because I use Emacs with evil-mode, I often type Esc (to enter normal mode) and then some other character, like k or j.  Sometimes when I hit these two keys quickly enough, it gets read as M-k or M-j instead, which does something unexpected like delete a paragraph.  How can I force these sequences to be interpreted as two separate keystrokes, Esc k, all the time?

I tried `(global-unset-key (kbd "M-k"))` but this seems to disable all keybindings starting with Meta.

I do have a working Meta key, so I would be okay with completely disabling the Esc-prefix way of type Meta.